# Finding the exact string without using match()

Tags: javascript

Here's my code. I'm trying to match the exact words that has been stored in the hit array[]. I only want to print what exactly is in myName variable. Can we do this without match() method?

```
var text = "Blaaah Bllaaah Bllaaah Paolo Blahhh Paaolo paolo";

var myName = "Paolo";

var hits = [];

for(var x=0; x<text.length; x++){
        if(text[x]===("P")){

            for(var i = x; i<(myName.length + x); i++){
                hits.push(text[i]);
                }
            }


    }

    if(hits.length === 0 ){
        console.log("Your name wasn't found");    
        }else{



            console.log(hits);

        }
```

Comment: declar your text as array

Comment: it is better go with match function. eg:  "Blaaah Bllaaah Bllaaah Paolo Blahhh Paaolo paolo".match(/\bPaaolo\b/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var text = "Blaaah Bllaaah Bllaaah Paolo Blahhh Paaolo paolo";

var myName = "Paolo";

var textArray = text.split(' ');
var hits = textArray.filter(function(value){ return value === myName; });

if(hits.length === 0 ){
  console.log("Your name wasn't found");    
}else{
  console.log(hits);
}
```

The solution uses `array.filter()` to find exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

A simple condition:

```
if(text.indexOf(myName) != -1) {
  // name found
}
```

or if you want a word match, just split the word list into an array of words:

```
if(text.split(' ').indexOf(myName) != -1) {
  // name found
}
```

---

See it live here:

```js
var text = "Blaaah Bllaaah Bllaaah Paolo Blahhh Paaolo paolo";

function findName(word) {
  var name = prompt('Enter name:');
  if (!name) 
    return;
  var t = word ? text.split(' ') : text;
  if(t.indexOf(name) != -1) {
    alert('Name ' + name + ' found!');
  }
  else {
    alert('Name ' + name + ' NOT found!');
  }
  findName(word);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="findName()">String match</button>
<button onclick="findName(true)">Word match</button>
```

Comment: this won't work for "PaoloPaolo". So it is not reasonless.

Comment: And it shouldn't... Can you see `PaoloPaolo` in the original text?

Comment: It should, it will find Paolo 2 times when there is no word "Paolo" in the text, but there is "PaoloPaolo" which we are not searching for

Comment: OP said he want find exact string not word

Comment: @simon, the ability to clearly read questions and analyze original OP's code would get you way farther than going on a downvote rampage...

Comment: it is bad approach to use indexof here if i use aolo as input what will be the output

Comment: @raghavendra, isn't OP looking just for a string match - and if present, show the input? I understand what you're saying, but he never mentioned a full work search.

Comment: it as per the question. it is enough give reason that he could use match function only using regex he can match boundaries of word and his string exactly

Comment: @raghavendra, fair enough, added a slight modification to my answer so it works both ways now.

Comment: but the question is about whether he can go with match or not. or it is better to go with another approach. what we can suggest..

Comment: Well, we can only guess, he never said why he doesn't want to use match... not sure reinventing the wheel is a good option here, at least unless OP clears up the question a bit.

Comment: @simon, great attitude.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var text = "Blaaah Bllaaah Bllaaah Paolo Blahhh Paaolo paolo";

var myName = "Paolo";

var foundArray = text.split(" ").filter(function(e){ return e == myName });

if (foundArray.length) { /* name is found */ }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `indexOf` methode :

`"Blaaah Bllaaah Bllaaah Paolo Blahhh Paaolo paolo".indexOf('Paolo')` => 23

`"Blaaah Bllaaah Bllaaah Paolo Blahhh Paaolo paolo".indexOf('Paolooo')` => -1

Answer (score -1):

You can use the simple fact of an exact match:
`if ("abc" == "abc")`

First you create an array with which you are going to match your search. Then you simply compare all these array elements with the code above. The result would be something like this:

```
var haystack = "Blaaah Bllaaah Bllaaah Paolo Paolo Blahhh Paaolo paolo";

var search = "Paolo";

// Create an array
var haystackArray = haystack.split(" ");
var hits =0;

// For each array element
for(var i = 0; i < haystackArray.length; i ++){
    // Check if this array element match exactly your search string
    if(search == haystackArray[i])
        hits++;
}
console.log(hits);
```